# How do I finish off downed enemies?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I played the previous two Arkham games and I know there was a way to jump on temporarily downed enemies (the ones with stars floating around their heads) and finish them off so they wouldn't get back up. I just started Arkham Origins and can't figure out how to do this, though, and looking in the control options didn't show me any particular button that I need to press.

I'm pretty sure I always had that ability from the start in the previous games. Have I just not unlocked it yet, or am I just not finding the right button combo to press?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PlayStation 3 button combination is R2 + Triangle and it is Right Trigger + Y on 360, this makes Batman leap on top of the downed enemy and knock them out. This move is available from the beginning of the game, no unlocking required.

Be wary using it though as it is time consuming and leaves you vulnerable to being attacked for a short period, similar to the previous games.

Thanks to Sterno for providing the 360 button combo.

Comment: Ok cool, I will add that info to my answer.

Comment: Cool. It looks like my problem is that I just can't get it to execute, even hitting the right buttons. I don't know if I'm standing in the wrong spot or what.

Comment: You may have to hold the left analog stick in the direction of the enemy you want to attack.

Comment: After going back and playing some Arkham City, I think the problem I was having was simply that Origins feels a little more finicky when it comes to targeting a downed opponent.

Comment: I find the combat timing really off and finicky in general, the entire game doesn't quite have the same level fine tuning as the previous two.

Comment: You have to input both the trigger and the buttons simultaneously, or it will not work. It is also useful to note that for the challenge levels, this move gives the **most points of any takedown**, using hits to build your combo and finishing off with this takedown is by far the easiest way to gain score.

Comment: For the PC version, it is Left CTRL + Right Click